# onClickListener() in overlapped views

Tags: android, user-interface, onclicklistener

I have a LinearLayout with two views, one is an ImageView and on the top I have a Button. (see the picture below)

But when I add the OnClickListener to the button AND to the ImageView only the one setted in the ImageView seems to work.

Note: This view is part of a fragment inside a ViewPager.

I do not know how to make both listeners work!

[image: layout]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_photo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:text="BACK"
            android:id="@+id/my_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/default_padding"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"/>
    </FrameLayout> 
        ...
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your button overlapped by your ImageView. That is why you cannot click your button.

Comment: use RelativeLayout